# vertx kafka client consume messages and do a REST api call sequentially

Tags: apache-kafka, vertx4, vertx-kafka-client

```
    protected void consume(KafkaReadStream<String, JsonObject> consumer) {
        consumer.handler(record -> {
           // call a REST API to write a value to DB
           doRestApi(record);  // such as client.postAbs(...).send(...)
        });
    }
```

For example, records in topic like,

```
{"createtime":"2021-10-29 00:03:49.0"}
{"createtime":"2021-10-29 00:03:50.0"}
{"createtime":"2021-10-29 00:03:56.0"}
...
{"createtime":"2021-10-29 00:13:56.0"}
```

When the record `{"createtime":"2021-10-29 00:03:49.0"}` was coming, the handler did a REST api call to save the `createtime=2021-10-29 00:03:49.0` to mongodb.
when the second record came, `createtime=2021-10-29 00:03:50.0` would be saved.
Then the third record, `createtime=2021-10-29 00:03:56.0` would be saved.
And so on.
I hope these messages to be handled sequentially. As a result, the createtime in the last message `2021-10-29 00:13:56.0` would be the final value in DB.

When I ran my code, the result value was random and the former value(such as `2021-10-29 00:03:56.0`) might be the final value.
How could I make the handler to run sequentially?

Comment: You've not said how many partitions your topic has, so if it's more than one, order is not guaranteed... I'd also recommend using Kafka Connect Mongo sink rather than write your own code to write to the database

Comment: Order is also not guaranteed if your doRestApi method is asynchronous

Comment: what if the topic has only one partition?

Comment: Still wouldn't necessarily addresses a non blocking http call and doesn't answer why you cannot use Kafka Connect